Node child-process exec command fails when interpolating a variable
I'm using nodes child-process with its exec function like this.
async function run (input: any) {
  console.log("======" + input)
  const ret = await exec(input, { cwd: 'src/lib/utils' });
  const output = {stdout: ret.stdout, stderr: ret.stderr, error: ret.error}
  return output
  // return ret.stdout, ret.stderr, ret.error
}

Basically it takes a command that looks like this that runs a linux command curl
curl 'https://localhost:8289/v1/request' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(<token)" \
    --data '{
         "request": "'"$(<data)"'"
    }' -k -s 

I need to interpolate some variables namely a token and some data. However since the data is JSON I need to include some additional characters for escaping. This command works fine from the command line however when it's called using child-process exec it fails with this error.
{"message":"Syntax error: offset=59, error=invalid character '\\n' in string literal"}


If I include the $(<data) directly inline it works fine. Obviously the escape characters are causing the problem here.

Ok so my problem was to do with the way I was using an echo command to create the variable. For some reason echo was removing all of the \n characters from the string.
